# Best book ever on Galois theory (and differential galois theory)

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, galois-theory, big-list, book-recommendation

Which is the single best book for Galois theory (that includes differential Galois theory)

that everyone who loves pure Mathematics should read?

Answer (score 6):

I always am a fan of Dummit and Foote's *Abstract Algebra*. I also would recommend Ian Stewart's *Galois Theory*. Another book you could try is David A Cox's *Galois Theory*. All of these books are more from the algebra side of things and would not have much to say about differential Galois theory.

I speak for myself here, but I am not sure there is a book that covers Galois theory from both an algebraic and a differential equations standpoint all within the same cover. The two topics are distinct enough that texts on them are usually separate (At least from what I have observed).